# How to set position of cell of collectionview swift?

Tags: ios, swift

i am using collectionview  to show image in full screen and allowing scrolling between different images. but when orientation will change it's not showing properly.[image: Here image of screen after orientation change].And this is my code

```
override func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval) {


//    collectionView.reloadData()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    if visibleCell != nil {

     collectionView.selectItem(at: visibleCell as IndexPath?, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)

     }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        print(cell.frame)
      cell.SectionImage.image = images[indexPath.row].image

      return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UICollectionView `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method to define height and width of cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 15.0
    let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = CGFloat(NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_ROW)

    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let width = (bounds.size.width - leftAndRightPaddings * (numberOfItemsPerRow+1)) / numberOfItemsPerRow
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, width)

    return layout.itemSize
}
```

Try it. And you will get your expected result.

Comment: No.its not right answer. width and height of cell is right but when orientation will change then cell position also not staying in right manner

Comment: @JayPatel reload collectionView when device orientation will change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the minimum spacing for cell and lines to 0.

[image]

After that return the size of cell equal to `UICollectionView` by using the delegate method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
     return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width, collectionView.frame.size.height)
}

override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    print_debug("change orientation")
}
```

Its work for me in the same situation.